# Android - youtube api r52 - "access not configured"

Tags: android, api-key, android-youtube-api

I am building a simple test android app, where I am trying to get data about a particular video. I have taken the SHA1 fingerprint of my debug keystore and created a google api key with it (and my package name). I have activated the youtube api service for it.

This is my code:

```
YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new GsonFactory(), new HttpRequestInitializer() {
    public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {}
}).setApplicationName("MyApp").build();

try {
    YouTube.Videos.List listVideosRequest = youtube.videos().list("snippet,contentDetails");
    listVideosRequest.setId("A3PDXmYoF5U");
    listVideosRequest.setKey(GoogleAPIKey.DEBUG_GOOGLE_API_KEY);
    VideoListResponse youtubeResponse = listVideosRequest.execute();

    List<Video> youtubeVideos = youtubeResponse.getItems();

    return youtubeVideos;

} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("MyApp", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    return null;
}
```

So, i always get an exception: 403, Access not configured.

I am running out of ideas, what could be wrong.
Anyone have successfully used the youtube api for android yet with an api key?

**Update:**

I just deeply debugged the google libraries in order to find, what the actual request looks like, that is sent to google. It is this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=A3PDXmYoF5U&key=[my-debug-google-api-key]&part=snippet,contentDetails
```

with these headers set:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: MyApp Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.15.0-rc (gzip)
```

I don't see anything wrong there.

Comment: Hello! Did you solve this problem?

Comment: nope, unfortunately not :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a lot of reading I found [this google doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/#guideCategories) :

> You must send an authorization token for every insert, update, and delete request. You must also send an authorization token for any request that retrieves the authenticated user's private data.
>
> In addition, some API methods for retrieving resources may support parameters that require authorization or may contain additional metadata when requests are authorized. For example, a request to retrieve a user's uploaded videos **may also contain private videos** if the request is authorized by that specific user.

So conclusion is simple - you should use API key only for reading non-private data while videos also may be private. In my case I've tried to load `Channels` anonymously - and it works when I requesting only `channel_id`. When I've requested for contentDetails (which contains link to uploads) - I've also got 403 error.

Comment: Thanks, will check soon, unfortunately i'm on holidays now :)